# CSS transition doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, transition

I tried a lot and already searched in Google but I don't find a solution for my problem:

I made a jsfiddle for you to see my source-code: [Click here for my Source Code](http://jsfiddle.net/EhfbJ/)

Everything works fine. But the transition doesn't work in Firefox.

Here is my Sourcecode because I have to post it too if I want to use a jsfiddle!

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Startseite</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projekte</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Java / Bukkit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Webdesign</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PHP | MySQL</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Über mich</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </nav>
```

// CSS down \\ HTML up

```
nav{
        background: #333;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;   
    }

nav ul{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li{
    float:left; 
}

nav ul li a{ 
    color: #fff;
    background: #585858;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

nav ul li a.active{
    background: #373737;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid black;    
}

nav ul li ul{
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

nav ul li ul li{
    float: none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul{
    overflow: visible;  
}

nav ul li:hover ul li a{
    padding: 10px;  
}

nav ul li ul li a{
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
       -moz-transition: 0.3s;
        -ms-transition: 0.3s;
         -o-transition: 0.3s;
            transition: 0.3s;               
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

Comment: I am using Firefox and transition works properly with your example.

Comment: Lol. How can that be... I check if I have to update my FF...

Comment: No this isn't the problem :/ I use version 28.0 the newest version of FF :/

Comment: Maybe. I just said what I have. Look this: http://gyazo.com/19b536d2dba4395b443da9728737e5a4 . Select mp4 for more smothier image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like removing the `overflow:hidden` from the container suddenly makes the transition work. This leads me to believe it's an "optimisation" in Firefox that doesn't compute the "hidden" element.

Personally, I've used this to produce a similar effect: Rather than hiding the element, give it `transform:scaleY(0);` normally, and `transform:scaleY(1);` on hover.

Comment: Removing the overlflow will show the ul --> not good. I will try your method!

Comment: I tried your method but I am not sure if I tried it the right way. Could you please edit the jsfiddle and send me the edited version?